# If a ref does not have ten authors and ten or more, but he still use "et al", how to mark "et al" red?

Tags: vba, ms-word

```VB
Sub testname()
    Dim d As Document, reg As Object, p As Paragraph, mt
    Set d = ActiveDocument: d.Content.HighlightColorIndex = 0
    Set reg = CreateObject("VBScript.Regexp")
    reg.Global = True: reg.Pattern = "[A-Z][a-z]*, ([A-Z].)+;"
    For Each p In d.Paragraphs
        If reg.Execute(p.Range.Text).count > 1 And reg.Execute(p.Range.Text).count < 10 And InStr(p, "et al") > 0 Then
          p.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
       End If  
    Next 
End Sub
With p.Range.Find                .Text = "et al"
                .MatchCase = False
                Do
                    .Execute
             If .Found Then
             selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
             End If
             Loop
             End With
```

Our company requires that a ref must have more than ten authors to use “et al”，(e.g., Author 1, A.B.; Author 2, A.B.; Author 3, A.B.; Author 4, A.B.; Author 5, A.B.; Author 6, A.B.; Author 7, A.B.; Author 8, A.B.; Author 9, A.B.; Author 10, A.B.; et al. Title of the article. Abbreviated Journal Name Year, Volume, page range.).
But some people use less than ten authors in the case of "et al". In this case, I would like to mark et al in red. I tried to edit the following code.
 I can only mark the entire paragraph, how to only mark "et al". Hope to get your help, thanks.

Comment: Find location of **et al** with `InStr()` and use [Excel Characters object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/characters-object-excel) to change color to `RGB(255,0,0)`. Oops, you should use [Word Characters object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/characters-object-word)

Comment: color can be changed with Replace format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627054/visual-basic-macro-changing-the-colour-of-specific-text?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks for Patric K, I used your method to solve  problem perfectly

Comment: @kerrry You may want to post your code to help OP? Think OP can do with `selection.Range.Characters(...).HighlightColorIndex = wdRed` or use the method @Slai pointed out.

Comment: @PatricK I try use your method   `With p.Range.Characters(InStr(p, "et al"))
             .HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
            End With` but I can highlight "e" only, if I want to highlight "et al", what should i do?  Thank you for your attention

Comment: Sorry @kerry, I thought Excel and Word has same usage. See this [Word Range Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Word-VBA/articles/working-with-range-objects), you should use **Range** and specifiy the `Start:=Instr(...)-1, End:=Instr(...)-1 + Len(...)`

Comment: The problem has been solved, thank you for your help