# How to change the font color of a string which starts with "$" and end with "F" or " A" in Ms word using a VBA code

Tags: ms-word

I m beginner and trying to learn and understand the codes. currently I m struck with changing the Font color for the string "$1mF" to green and "$1mA" to red in the MS word document. The start and end are constant i.e starts with $ and ends with either A or F. The purpose is that string ending with F denotes a favorable and positive impact(i.e green) and string ending with A denotes unfavorable and negative impact(i.e red) that too bold. I doing it manually as of now. I did try few examples i found on this site and tweaked them a bit as well but dint quite get through the desired results.

Any quick help on this would be grateful.

Comment: You should show what you have then people will be more open to getting you your answer.

Comment: Thnk u for d suggestion.. i will do follow it going fwd before i post a question.

Answer (score 2):

This code will probably do the trick

```
Sub ChangeColorRedGreen()  

  With Selection.Find 
    .ClearFormatting 
    .MatchWholeWord = True 
    .MatchCase = False 
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Execute FindText:="$*F"
    .Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorGreen
  End With
  Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

  With Selection.Find 
    .ClearFormatting 
    .MatchWholeWord = True 
    .MatchCase = False 
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Execute FindText:="$*A"
    .Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
  End With
  Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

also read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193977(v=office.14).aspx
a similar (not identical) case here: [Find all instances of yellow text and change font color to red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691154/find-all-instances-of-yellow-text-and-change-font-color-to-red)