# Word VBA Find text of a certain color and insert a space ahead of it

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am new to VBA in MS Word, and only somewhat comfortable with VBA in Excel.

I am trying to process a Word file that has some special information attached to many words. The information is conveyed by changing the color, size, and position of the text, but there is no space between the word and the information.

[image: Unprocessed Text]

In order to do some other processing, I need to add a space between the information text and the actual word:

[image: Processed Text]

Using VBA I am able to find the informational text by color, using a slight variation on the method described [here](http://'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691154/find-all-instances-of-yellow-text-and-change-font-color-to-red/17491115).  I can replace it with "Test".  But what I want to do is replace it with a space plus the infromational text.  Or perhaps just magically insert a space right before the informational text.

Ideas?

This code:

```
Sub ChangeColorWithReplace()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Color = RGB(120, 48, 191)
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    'Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.Color = wdColorRed
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "test"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Produces this result:

[image: Incorrectly Processed Text]

Comment: The crux of the matter, using the Find method, is extracting the actual text found!  Since the search is based on font color, the text could be anything.  Once the actual text is extracted from the Find method, a simple concatenation could be used to replace that text with a space plus that text.  Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to extract the actual text...

Comment: Show your code up to now

Comment: Code shown.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A neat thing with Word's Find/Replace functionality is that you can use special characters to perform actions like this. Click the "More" button, the "Special" to see a list.

In this case, what you want is to retain the "Find text" in your replacement, which is the character set: ^& which I've added to your sample code, below.

```
Sub ChangeColorWithReplace()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Color = RGB(120, 48, 191)
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting

    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = "^&test"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchByte = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Comment: @diakonos1984 `.Replacement.Text` would be `" ^&"`, and `^&` is the special character for "Find What Text"

Comment: That was it!  Thanks so much, Cindy and @Slai. I knew it had to be something simple, just couldn't figure out what it was.